# Use same animation at different times, in different elements

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I have several TextView I want to animate. I want to use the same animation but that start at different times for each TextView. I searched but could not find how. I tried setStartOffset, but it seems that I'm not using as directed. Someone could help me?
This is my code:

```
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f,
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, -1500.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f);
    animation.setDuration(3000);
    tvNumero1.startAnimation(animation);

    //this fails:
    animation.setStartOffset(300);
    tvNumero2.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Have you tried defining two animation objects, one for each? The Handler approach might be overdoing it, as Android already provides you with the offset being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created different animations for the element, alternatively, you could use an animaiton from an xml resource. Here's the code:

```
//First Animation
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f,
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, -1500.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f);
animation.setDuration(3000);
tvNumero1.startAnimation(animation);

//Second Animation
TranslateAnimation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f,
    Animation.ABSOLUTE, -1500.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f);
animation2.setDuration(3000);
animation2.setStartOffset(300);
tvNumero2.startAnimation(animation2);
```

Alternatively, you can define the animation in an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:fromYDelta="-1500"
    android:toYDelta="0" >

</translate>
```

Here is the code for XML:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.text_move);
tvNumero1.startAnimation(animation);

Animation animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.text_move);
animation2.setStartOffset(300);
tvNumero2.startAnimation(animation2);
```

Previous code it seems it's waiting for the offset and then starts the whole animation, I changed it to 3 seconds, and it takes those 3 seconds to start.

Comment: Thank you so much Toguard. That he was looking for. The choice of the code had thought, but I needed something that would use less code since many equal animations that I need (it is a rain of elements). The choice of XML code is perfect. Thank you very much for your time